# *backStack funtions not available in NavController?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

Playing with the new fragment navigation, I wanted to dump the current backstack to the log for information purposes to learn how it all works.  The problem is, when I obtain the NavController, it doesn't appear to have any of the backstack properties or functions.

Here's a simple example:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
...
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        // Dump the back stack
        Log.i("MyFragment", findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.destination.label)
    }
...
```

In Studio, [currentBackStackEntry](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/NavController#getcurrentbackstackentry) is not found. It's also true for `backStackEntry` and `previousBackStackEntry` (or using the functions explicitly).  Of course, when compiling, I get an unresolved reference error.

I'm using:

- Android Studio 4.1.1
- Kotlin plugin 1.4.10
- navigation-fragment-ktx & navigation-ui-ktx 2.3.1

I can use other functions/properties with the NavController, such as obtaining the graph.  It's only the *backStack* properties that don't seem to exist.

So, the question is why aren't those properties available, yet documented (they're supposed to be there since navigation-*:2.2.0) and do others see the same issue?